# Publish with FTP not available in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ftp

I have a WPF app I want to publish using FTP. But the FTP profile doesn't show for me, despite the fact that it shows in Microsoft's Docs for [Deploying your Visual Studio app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components-resources?view=vs-2022#ftpftps-server).

I know it's possible because I did it in VS 2019, although someone did mention that the option was going away. Can anyone help here, is there some kind of service that needs to be reenabled.

I tried enabling ASP.NET development with Visual Studio Installer, but that didn't help.

Comment: Publish to a folder and then use an(other) FTP client to upload it to the target matchine?

Comment: @mm8 That's what I do using FileZilla, however, I specifically remembered using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 to publish the landing page and application with FTP built in. The launch page would look like this: https://snipboard.io/elES3j.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WPF` does not have an FTP publishing option.

[image]

Please showcase your posting actions in 2019.

Maybe you want to use asp.net core.

[image]

Update:

In ClickOnce for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 or later, you set deployment properties using the Publish tool instead of the Publish wizard and the Publish page of the Project Designer. For more information, see [`Deploy a .NET Windows application using ClickOnce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2022) and [`ClickOnce for .NET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-deployment-dotnet?view=vs-2022).

Based on your illustration, I found the following settings in 2022 VS Community 17.4.1 WPF .Net Framework 4.8:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't check 2019 yet, but 2017 didn't offer it as a publishing profile, but nevertheless gave me the option to use FTP under Build > Publish. https://snipboard.io/HWb46i.jpg Here's what the launch page would look like: https://snipboard.io/elES3j.jpg

Comment: I can choose to use FTP under "publish->publish wizard->browse->ftp" in 2022.

Comment: I found in the VS 2022 docs that, "In ClickOnce for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 or later, you set deployment properties using the Publish tool instead of the Publish wizard and the Publish page of the Project Designer." This was the reason why I couldn't get it, your answer helped me realize that. Thanks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/publishing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022